# VaryByCustom and model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, outputcache

I have a class I model bind and I want to use output caching with it.  I can't find a way to access the bound object in `GetVaryByCustomString`

For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ... More properties here
}

public class MyClassModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
   public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
      var model = new MyClass();
      ... build the class       
      return model;
    }
}
```

I set the binder in Global.cs

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(MyClass), new MyClassModelBinder());
```

And then use output caching like this.

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300, VaryByCustom = "myClass")]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyClass myClass)
{
   .......

public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
   ... check we're working with 'MyClass'

   var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
   var myClass = (MyClass)routeData.Values["myClass"]; <-- This is always null
```

myClass isn't in the route table event though the model binder fired.

Any help as always will be most welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The model binder doesn't add the model to the `RouteData`, so you cannot expect to fetch it from there.

One possibility is to store the model inside the `HttpContext` inside your custom model binder:

```
public class MyClassModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
   public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
      var model = new MyClass();
      // ... build the class

      // Store the model inside the HttpContext so that it is accessible later
      controllerContext.HttpContext.Items["model"] = model;
      return model;
    }
}
```

and then retrieve it inside the `GetVaryByCustomString` method using the same key (`model` in my example):

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    var myClass = (MyClass)context.Items["model"];

    ...
}
```